# How to get Notepad2 to show Recently Use Files?

Tags: windows-10, notepad2

It never saves my most recently used files at all.  How do I enable this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem. To fix it I ran Notepad2 as administrator and selected Settings->"Save settings now".

Also it looks like you need to run it as administrator every time otherwise recent files aren't remembered.

Answer (score 1):

Select *Settings -> Other Settings -> Remember Recent Files*.

[image: How to enable recently use files in Notepad2]

Comment: What version of Notepad2 are you using?
– What does it say when you press [F1] on your keyboard?
I'm myself on [4.2.25](https://i.imgur.com/K737Zvs.png),
which I believe is the last stable version ever
[offered by Florian Balmer](https://www.flos-freeware.ch/) in May 2011.
I know
[Notepad2 has been further developed by others](https://www.rizonesoft.com/downloads/notepad3)
since then.